# How to view .dmp file on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have created a "minidump" file using the Visual Studio 2008 C++ debugger (Debug menu -> Save dump as...).  I am running on Windows 7, 64-bit.

What program can I run to view the contents of the dump file in a meaningful way?

Comment: Only a debugger can show a meaningful view of a .dmp file.  You have one: Visual Studio.

Comment: @Hans - How do I open a .dmp file from within Visual Studio 2008?  When I open the file, it displays as raw hex.

Comment: Use File + Open + Project/Solution and change the filter (above the Open button) to "Dump files".  You are using File + Open + File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What information are you trying to get out of it?

[WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561300%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is my tool of choice.

It's part of the Windows SDK. You can get download links from here: http://www.windbg.org/

Note that there are three plaforms for it - x86, x64, and IA64. You want the version based on what the application is designed for, not your architecture. So if it is a 32-bit process, either by running on x86 Windows or WOW64 on x64 Windows, you want the x86 version. Only use x64 if the dmp came from a 64-bit process.

Comment: How do I download / run that application?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) is the best.

It is supplied as part of [Microsoft Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en).